# Spring не может найти шаблоны html по заданному пути

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Всем доброго времени суток, не так давно изучаю spring, и частенько сталкивался с проблемами, которые удавалось найти и исправить, но в этот раз я нашёл только похожие вопросы, которые всё же не смогли мне помочь исправить эту проблему, поэтому пишу этот вопрос и буду максимально благодарен любой помощи!)

Суть приложения состоит в записи/удалении/изменении и выводе строк из БД.

У меня есть 4 контроллера, репозиторий и 4 шаблонных html-страницы.
После запуска приложения выдается вот такая ошибка:

```
An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/src/main/resources/templatesindex.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/src/main/resources/templates/index.html]")
```

Контроллер для главной страницы:

```
import com.example.web.Entitys.Employees;
import com.example.web.repos.EmployeeRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
public class MOdul {
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepo nameRepo;

    public MOdul(EmployeeRepo nameRepo) {
        this.nameRepo = nameRepo;
    }


    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String saveEmployee(Model model) {
        return "index";


    }

    @PostMapping("/index")
    public String formPost(@RequestParam String name,
                           @RequestParam String lastname,
                           @RequestParam String secondname,
                           @RequestParam String sex,
                           @RequestParam String dateofbirth,
                           @RequestParam String Work,
                           @RequestParam String number, Model model) {
        Employees employees = new Employees(name, lastname, secondname,sex, dateofbirth, Work, number);
        nameRepo.save(employees);

        return "index";


    }





}
```

Шаблон главной страницы:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="startbootstrap-modern-business-1.0.5/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="startbootstrap-modern-business-1.0.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Main page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "main">
    <form action="/index" method="post">
        <label>
            Имя
            <input type="text" name="name">
        </label><br>
        <label>
            Фамилия
            <input type="text" name="secondname">
        </label><br>
        <label>
            Отчество
            <input type="text" name="lastname">
        </label><br>
        <label>
            Пол
            <input type="text" name="sex">
        </label><br>
        <label>
            Дата рождения
            <input type="text" name="dateofbirth">
        </label><br>
        <label>
            Должность
            <input type="text" name="Work">
        </label><br>
        <label>
            Номер телефона
            <input type="text" name="number">
        </label><br>
        <button type="submit" >Отправить</button>


    </form>

</div>

<a href="/delete"> Delete User </a><br>
<a href="/change"> Change User </a><br>
<a href="/Employee"> Список работников</a>
</body>
</html>
```

`SpringConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example.web")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("src/main/resources/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }




}
```

Структура проекта:

[image: Структура проекта]

P.S. полная ошибка:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/src/main/resources/templates/index.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/src/main/resources/templates/index.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:235)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:649)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1103)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1077)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:372)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:192)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1415)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1159)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1098)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:631)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/src/main/resources/templates/index.html]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:164)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.templateresource.SpringResourceTemplateResource.reader(SpringResourceTemplateResource.java:103)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:223)
    ... 40 more
```

Comment: Приведите весь стек ошибки, а не часть, у вас не «не находит» у вас не может распознать, и в тексте ошибки будет в чем проблема.

Comment: @Mira извиняюсь, отредачил, не понимаю почему путь пишется как "/src/main/resources/templatesindex.html" без слэша между templates и index

Comment: А вы там где префикс задаете пробовали / в конце поставить после templates?

Comment: @Mira да я заметил отсутствие слэша, добавил, но проблему это не решило, стек выходит точно такой же, правда уже есть раздел между template и index.html, сейчас отредактирую выводимую оишбку

Answer (score 1):

1. После сборки Spring Boot приложения, в jar файле не будет директории `src/main/resources` (причина `FileNotFoundException`), поможет замена

   `templateResolver.setPrefix("src/main/resources/templates/");` на

   `templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");`
2. Spring Boot может сам, без явного файла конфигурации, настроиться на работу с Thymeleaf.
3. `@RequestMapping` без указания метода будет реагировать не только на `GET` но и на другие, например `DELETE` или `PATCH`.

Answer (score 0):

В контроллере (во всех методах ) попробуйте так, убрать имя страницы из аннотации:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
    public String saveEmployee(Model model) {
        return "index";


    }
```

Потому что возвращаемым значением вы уже задаете имя шаблона, в аннотации имя повторно не надо указывать

Comment: убрал, но теперь выскакивает 404 ошибка, а сам спринг в логах говорит что не удалось найти шаблоны по заданному пути.

Comment: То есть все таки в вашей версии он по пути шаблон видел, но вправду  не мог распарсить, вероятно он ожидает по этому адресу данные на вход (у вас  контроллер принимает Model model, а страничка ничего не передает. Для отладки уберите передаваемый параметр из метода временно, и сам html сократите до простого hello world в одну строку

Comment: убрал параметры, 404 исчезла, но обратно вернулась та ошибка которую описал выше, в логах все также не может почему-то найти templates, я без понятия как это можно исправить, ведь везде где можно прописал полный правильный путь

Comment: Вы прочитайте мой комментарий выше - он находит шаблон, он не может распарсить, попробуйте убрать входной параметр у контроллера Model model  - этот параметр ожидается на вход, а вы его не даете,  и сам  html сократите до  hello world

Comment: Попробовал как вы описали выше, все та же ошибка, я подумал что возможно это из за неправильного пути к bootstrap, но увы… я незнаю что еще сделать

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, не парсит из-за того, что страничке не указан шаблонизатор

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```